# Show line number on Borland C++Builder 6 (2002)

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder-6

I know it's a old IDE, but in my job I have to work with it.

I spend a couple of days searching where could I set the line numbers to show on the left side of the text editor, but I couldnt find.

I'm still hoping it's possible, never saw any IDE that didn't have that.

Comment: You could always try finding an old version of coderush on "the net". If my memory serves me correctly it added line numbers to bcb6 and some other interesting code visuals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll not find it.  Only Borland c++ 2005 and higher can do this.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Like bbarnhart said, BCB6 does not support displaying line numbers in the gutter.  The only thing it does do is display in the lower-left corner of the statuts bar the line number and column number where the edit caret is currently located.

Comment: Shouldn't you guys be calling yourselves TeamCG or TeamE by now?

Comment: That's up to the powers-that-be to decide.

Comment: is it just me or does that really seem like a silly oversight. How could it not have such a basic thing like line number display in the gutter? I was also looking for this and like the OP was unable to find it.

Comment: As has already be stated, newer versions of the IDE do support line numbers in the gutter now.  BCB 6 did not.